# How to merge two arrays with keeping numeric keys as it is

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating two array where numeric keys may match, but when i m using array merge or + operator then its merge with automatic numeric keys. I want  to keep original numeric keys.

```
foreach($qr1 as $b){
    $day=(int)substr($b->dob,8,2);                  
    $events_arr1[$day]=$b;                          
}
```

it return a array like

> Array  (  [4] =>  Arnab Roy [13] =>  Kaushik De [14] =>  Brett , Test
>   )

```
foreach($qr2 as $b){
    $day=(int)substr($b->dob,8,2);                  
    $events_arr2[$day]=$b;
}
```

it return a array like

> Array  (  [14] =>  shouts1, shouts2 )

```
        $events_arr=$events_arr1+$events_arr2;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($events_arr);
        exit;
```

it return a array like

```
     Array
     (
         [4] =>  Arnab Roy

         [13] =>  Kaushik De

         [14] =>  Brett , Test

    )
```

but last array index not merge.. dont know why

Comment: What would you expect the result of that merge to look like?

Comment: Array
     (
         [4] =>  Arnab Roy

         [13] =>  Kaushik De

         [14] =>  Brett , Test ,shouts1, shouts2

    )

Comment: So you want to concatenate the two strings in that key? Then there's no predefined function that does that, you'll have to do it yourself in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same key more than once in an array, that's why it can't merge the second array : The key "14" already exists in the first array.

Comment: i want to merge 14 index element in a same key with keep index same as  14

Answer (score 0):

It is never possible to create an array with the same key.  You cannot merge two arrays if your array key is the same.  As we can see, you have the same key '14' in both arrays.  Try to do your functionality instead of `array_merge` or concat array. My suggestion is that you can convert both arrays into a string and concat both strings.